# How can I filter keywords from a csv file using Python

Tags: python, csv, filter, dataset

I am trying to write a Python code which opens a csv file, filter keywords from specific columns and display the results.

The csv file has 500 rows and 7 columns separated by comma.

That's my code. Not sure if makes much sense.

```py
with open('csv_file') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in readCSV:
        Title == row[4]
        Author(s) == row[5]
        Genre == row [7]
        if row[1] == entrada:
            results.append()

    print(Results.format(entrada, results))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for single column

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('path/to/file.csv')

print(df.loc[df['Author(s)'].str.contains(keyword)]])
```

you can search for multiple keywords like this :

`keyword="Mat|Tom"`

Comment: That worked perfectly, because I create a new file with a single column. Thank you very much! I appreciate your help!

Comment: What if the user wants to search for the ISBN number of a book. In the csv file there is a column for ISBN number of each book.

Comment: @BecKy wouldnt changing the the column name to 'ISBN' helps? 
for exact match this also works: df[df['IBSN'] == 'ibsn_to_search'].

Comment: it means there is no column with that name you can get a sense of your dataframe by `print(df.head())`, also list columns by `print(list(df.columns))`

Comment: I modified the original answer. you can use .loc